# Javascript GMT/BST dates on a BST machine

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a web app that always stores the dates as UTC, but they need to be displayed to the user as GMT/BST, respectively.

I have a UTC/GMT date (30th March 2013 22:00), I'm moving this hourly to cross the GMT/BST boundary. I am manipulating the date using the `setTime()` method.

So, my input timestamps, display time, UTC time are as follows:

- 1364808000 - 22:00 GMT+0000 - 22:00
- 1364685500 - 23:00 GMT+0000 - 23:00
- 1364688000 - 00:00 GMT+0000 - 00:00
- 1364691600 - 02:00 GMT+0100 - 01:00
- 1364695200 - 03:00 GMT+0100 - 02:00
- 1364698800 - 04:00 GMT+0100 - 03:00

When the machine is in GMT, it outputs:

- 1364808000 - 22:00 GMT+0000 - 22:00
- 1364685500 - 23:00 GMT+0000 - 23:00
- 1364688000 - 00:00 GMT+0000 - 00:00
- 1364691600 - 02:00 GMT+0100 - 01:00
- 1364695200 - 03:00 GMT+0100 - 02:00
- 1364698800 - 04:00 GMT+0100 - 03:00

When the machine is in BST, it outputs:

- 1364808000 - 22:00 GMT+0000 - 22:00
- 1364685500 - 23:00 GMT+0000 - 23:00
- 1364688000 - 00:00 GMT+0000 - 00:00
- 1364691600 - 00:00 GMT+0000 - 01:00
- 1364695200 - 02:00 GMT+0100 - 02:00
- 1364698800 - 03:00 GMT+0100 - 03:00

Now, in my mind those last 3 dates aren't correct.

Any ideas?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twilson/WRbyh/

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the machine, whilst on BST time, was not configured to automatically change the timezone to match the date.

As a result on the 6th April, it was still listed as **GMT Standard Time**, rather than **GMT Daylight Time**.

Ticking the Automaticlly change option, fixed this issue.